# Removing Magento Recently Viewed Product from all pages except of Product view page

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to remove the "Recently Viewed Products" from all pages using local.xml but show it only of Product View page.

I display "Recently Viewed Products" on Product View Page using:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">    
    <reference name="content">         
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="right.reports.product.viewed" as="recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />     
    </reference> 
</catalog_product_view>
```

Now to hide it from all the other pages I use following code:

```
<default>
<reference name="right">  
    <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
</reference> 
</default>
```

But than it disappears also from Product View page!

How can I achieve that Recently Viewed Product is hidden on all pages except of the Product View Page?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HomTom just change the block name `name="right.reports.product.viewed"`  fro this code

`<block type="reports/product_viewed" name="right.reports.product.viewed" as="recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />`    of product page .

As two blocks have same name to it.`<default>` handler is working also on all `frontend page`

**Default handler is also remove Recently Viewed Products from  product page view**

So,change

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">    
    <reference name="content">         
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="right.reports.onlyproduct.viewed" as="recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />     
    </reference> 
</catalog_product_view>
```

**name="right.reports.product.viewed"** change to `name="right.reports.onlyproduct.viewed"`

Comment: You can't imagin how much time I spent on this one.
Thanks a lot for the great explenation.

Comment: You r welcome...

Comment: Your solution is great, however I had to add this in to my local.xml to get it work:
    <remove name="left.reports.product.viewed" />
I guess this is a Magento Bug.

Comment: No..it is magento feature

Answer (score -3):

With CSS:

```
.block-viewed {display: none; }
```

Comment: This is bad advice.

Comment: This is not a feasible solution.

Comment: It worked for me